# 'agsXMPP.MessageGrabber' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Tags: c#

here's the code:

```
  XmppClientConnection xmpp = new XmppClientConnection();
        xmpp.Server = "gmail.com";
        xmpp.ConnectServer = "talk.google.com";
        xmpp.Username = "aleksandr.gordon";
        xmpp.Password = "password";
        xmpp.Open();

        agsXMPP.Jid JID = new Jid("thegabmeister1@gmail.com");
        xmpp.MessageGrabber.Add(JID, new agsXMPP.Collections.BareJidComparer(), new MessageCB(xmpp.MessageGrabber), null);

        agsXMPP.protocol.client.Message msg = new agsXMPP.protocol.client.Message();
        msg.Type = agsXMPP.protocol.client.MessageType.chat;
        msg.To = JID;
        msg.Body = "how u doing" + DateTime.Now.ToString();

        xmpp.OnLogin += delegate(object o) { xmpp.Send(msg); };
```

updated new code:

```
    agsXMPP.Jid JID = new Jid("thegabmeister@gmail.com");
    xmpp.MessageGrabber.Add(JID, new agsXMPP.Collections.BareJidComparer(),
        new MessageCB(delegate(object sender, agsXMPP.protocol.client.Message msg, object data)
    {
    }), null);
    agsXMPP.protocol.client.Message msg1 = new agsXMPP.protocol.client.Message();
    msg1.Type = agsXMPP.protocol.client.MessageType.chat;
    msg1.To = JID;
    msg1.Body = "how u doing" + DateTime.Now.ToString();

    xmpp.OnLogin += delegate(object o) { xmpp.Send(msg1); };
```

what am i ddoing wrong? why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably need to pass a delegate method, try adding this method to your code

```
void Login() {
    XmppClientConnection xmpp = new XmppClientConnection();
    xmpp.Server = "gmail.com";
    xmpp.ConnectServer = "talk.google.com";
    xmpp.Username = "aleksandr.gordon";
    xmpp.Password = "password";
    xmpp.Open();

    agsXMPP.Jid JID = new Jid("thegabmeister1@gmail.com");
    xmpp.MessageGrabber.Add(JID, new agsXMPP.Collections.BareJidComparer(), new MessageCB(GrabMessage), null);

    agsXMPP.protocol.client.Message msg = new agsXMPP.protocol.client.Message();
    msg.Type = agsXMPP.protocol.client.MessageType.chat;
    msg.To = JID;
    msg.Body = "how u doing" + DateTime.Now.ToString();

    xmpp.OnLogin += delegate(object o) { xmpp.Send(msg); };
}

protected void GrabMessage(object sender, agsXMPP.protocol.client.Message msg, object data) {
}
```

this is the last thing i can suggest but the above method works and will fix your problem, unless you have other problems elsewhere:

```
xmpp.MessageGrabber.Add(JID, new agsXMPP.Collections.BareJidComparer(),
    new MessageCB(delegate(object sender, agsXMPP.protocol.client.Message msg, object data) {
    if (msg.Body != null) {
        MessageBox.Show(msg.Body);
    }
    }), null);
```

Comment: As a method in that class - you might want to rename it to something different `xmpp.MessageGrabber.Add(JID, new agsXMPP.Collections.BareJidComparer(), new MessageCB(<put the method name here>), null);`

Comment: altered my answer, to give you a better idea...see if that works for you

Comment: Error 1 'agsXMPP.XmppClientConnection' does not contain a definition for 'GrabMessage' and no extension method 'GrabMessage' accepting a first argument of type 'agsXMPP.XmppClientConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/JabberClient.aspx if you scroll down to "Sending and Receiving Messages" you'll see how to implement it - same as what i wrote but that site might give you a better understanding.

Comment: looks pretty goood but still i think there should be an easy solution for my problem

Comment: that is the solution and it's an easy one - i've posted one more to help you out but there's not much more i can say

Comment: ive revised it to show you my new code, the good news is that it doesnt give me errors but doesnt do anything either

Comment: cool, glad that works. Now you have to just add your code you want to handle the message. Within the delegate you have access to msg.Body and so forth. I'm not sure what you're trying to do so that is up to you but your code to handle the message goes inside the delegate - i'm updating the answer to show you

Comment: im just trying to send a message, but its not sendin git!

Comment: well, the code i was helping with doesn't relate to sending messages only receiving them. I would say make sure your logon delegate is being fired since that's where you're automatically sending your crafted message.

Answer (score 1):

```
new MessageCB(MessageGrabber)
```

should probably be:

```
new MessageCB(xmpp.MessageGrabber)
```

As for what you're doing wrong, you are using the type `agsXMPP.MessageGrabber` like a variable, which will not compile.

Comment: thank you i just tried that but did not work, getting same error

Comment: @...? - if you double-click on the error in Visual Studio it will take you directly to the offending statement